# Networkx graph has more nodes tha in my modelist file

Tags: python, twitter, networkx

I am currently working on a graph of twitter users, where I have 2 csv files, one is the node list with close to 147,000 nodes and the other is a edge list with all the relationships between the users.

When I import the files to networkx and use the `info()` method on the graph it tells me i have upwards of 5,000,000 nodes in the graph (The figure is similar if I use `info()` on both the directed and undirected version of the graph)

I have tried this with smaller datasets and the number of nodes matched the number in my node list file. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

many thanks

**EDIT**

The code I am using can be seen below

```
import csv

import networkx as nx

import pandas as pd

with open('node list.csv', 'r') as nodecsv: # Open the file
    nodereader = csv.reader(nodecsv) # Read the csv
    # Retrieve the data (using Python list comprhension and list slicing to remove the header row, see footnote 3)
    nodes = [n for n in nodereader][1:]

node_names = [n[0] for n in nodes] # Get a list of only the node names

with open('edge list.csv', 'r') as edgecsv: # Open the file
    edgereader = csv.reader(edgecsv) # Read the csv
    edges = [tuple(e) for e in edgereader][1:] # Retrieve the data
    
print(len(node_names))

print(len(edges))

G = nx.Graph()

# G.add_nodes_from(node_names)
G.add_edges_from(edges)


print(nx.info(G))

print(total_nodes)

follower_count_dict = {}
friend_count_dict = {}
staus_count_dict = {}
created_at_dict = {}






for node in nodes: # Loop through the list, one row at a time
    follower_count_dict[node[0]] = node[1]
    friend_count_dict[node[0]] = node[2]
    staus_count_dict[node[0]] = node[3]
    created_at_dict[node[0]] = node[4]

    

#print(  user_followers_count_dict)

nx.set_node_attributes(G, follower_count_dict, 'follower_count')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, friend_count_dict, 'friend_count')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, staus_count_dict, 'staus_count')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, created_at_dict, 'created_at')



DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_nodes_from(node_names)
DG.add_edges_from(edges)


nx.set_node_attributes(DG, follower_count_dict, 'follower_count')
nx.set_node_attributes(DG, friend_count_dict, 'friend_count')
nx.set_node_attributes(DG, staus_count_dict, 'staus_count')
nx.set_node_attributes(DG, created_at_dict, 'created_at')
```

Snapshot of user list file

[image: Snapshot of user file (nodelist)]

Snapshot of edge list file

[image: Snapshot or edgelist file]

Comment: In order to get help you should show a small example of how the 2 files look like and the code you are using to import them

Comment: hi @abc thanks for your reply, I have edited the original post

Answer (score 1):

Your edge list includes nodes that do not appear in your node list.  So when those edges are added, networkx adds the nodes as well.

Reasons for this could include the nodes being treated as strings with different white space (perhaps '\n' at the end), or nodes being treated as integers in some cases and strings in others.

A way to deal with this is that before you add the edges, do a loop that checks whether each node is in the graph and if not, prints out the node:

```
for edge in edges:
    for node in edge:
        if node not in G:
            print(node)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Joel. That makes sense, I had to do some pre processing on the edge list file and may have skipped some steps. I'll have another look and try your solution

Comment: Quick comment - my "solution" isn't going to solve it in and of itself, but it will help you identify where the problem is occurring.